# In puppeteer, what does the term pageFunction mean when using methods page.$eval() and page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using these two methods to get the text of an HTML element. For example:

```
let elHandle = await page.$("#product");
let productName = await elHandle.evaluate(element => {
    return element.textContent;
});
```

And

```
let productName = await page.$eval("#product", element => {
    return element.textContent;
});
```

In both examples I pass the "pageFunction" as parameter to both methods. But what is a page function in puppeteer?

Edit:
I should add that the following passage is given in the documentation but I don't understand what it means:

pageFunction <function|string> Function to be evaluated in the page context

Edit: typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Puppeteer script is running in NodeJS. NodeJS lauches the browser and goes through your script. If you use `console.log('hello')` in your script it will log it to your terminal using NodeJS.

A page function is a function that Puppeteer (through NodeJS) turns into a string, sends to the browser, and then runs inside the Chromium instance. If you use `console.log('hello')` in your page function, it will log it to the console in the browser.

**Example based on yours**

```js
console.log('hello') // Displayed in terminal running your script.

page.$eval("#product", element => {
    // We are now inside the browser and can use DOM APIs!

    console.log('hello') // Displayed in browser's console
});
```